# Where to Hide Your Privates in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, private-members

What's the convention/rule/preference/diktat about where private instance variables should be declared and why?

```
// someClass.h

@interface someClass : NSObject {
@private
// Here in the class declaration?
}
// ...
@end

// someClass.m

@interface someClass () {
// Here in the class extension? This seems to be obj-c's version
// of the C++ Pimpl idiom.
}
@end

@implementation someClass {
// Here in the class definition? BTW, what's the default scope here?
// Seems like it should be @private. I haven't been able to find much
// documentation about this declaration block.
}
// ...
@end
```

Can anyone comment on the appropriate use of these three sections or point to a good web resource on this? Thanks!

Comment: The title's a bit cheeky but I'm serious about the question. I haven't been able to find thorough documentation on this topic. Nothing I've seen from books (Kochan, Sadun, Ali) and Apple doc gives a thorough and comprehensive discussion about it.

Comment: The default scope of ivars in the `@implementation` block is `@private`. However this is almost certainly irrelevant, because unless you're putting multiple classes in the same `.m` file, no other classes can even *see* the ivars, which is a prerequisite to attempting to access them.

Comment: Rob, the link you mention does answer my question. All the contributors here have helped clarify this topic for me. If I could I would put a check on both yours and Nikolai's answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today it's best practice to put them in the `@implementation` or in a (non-public) class extension.

Ivars are never of interest to clients of a class, so they should not be visible in the public API (the header).

There's not much difference in putting them in the @implementation or in a class-extension. For consistence I always put them in the @implementation.

Comment: for consistence I always put them into a class extension.

Comment: A follow-up question if I may: what would you advocate for classes that want to expose instance variables to subclasses? Personally I tend to prefer a category with appropriate getters and possibly declared elsewhere than in the main 'public' header.

Comment: @Tommy I consider this breaking the encapsulation. Other classes (subclass or not) never should access ivars.